# Using Group By and Max + Sum function

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a table like below:

| PJ_CODE | Questionnaire | SortQ | Answer | SortA | Questionnaire_Type | Customer_ID | TotalAnswer | Activity_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| J005 | Purpose | 05 | A | 0504 | Visit | 426766 | 0.5 | 04/12/2023 |
| J005 | Purpose | 05 | C | 0503 | Visit | 426766 | 0.5 | 04/12/2023 |
| J005 | Purpose | 05 | B | 0501 | Visit | 426955 | 1 | 05/12/2023 |
| J005 | Purpose | 05 | B | 0501 | Visit | 427441 | 1 | 05/12/2023 |
| J005 | Purpose | 05 | B | 0501 | Visit | 427473 | 1 | 07/12/2023 |
| J005 | Purpose | 05 | B | 0501 | Visit | 402564 | 1 | 08/12/2023 |
| J005 | Purpose | 05 | A | 0504 | Visit | 426766 | 0.5 | 09/12/2023 |
| J005 | Purpose | 05 | C | 0503 | Visit | 426766 | 0.5 | 09/12/2023 |
| J005 | Purpose | 05 | B | 0501 | Visit | 188237 | 1 | 10/12/2023 |
| J005 | Purpose | 05 | C | 0503 | Visit | 381630 | 1 | 11/12/2023 |
| J005 | Purpose | 05 | A | 0504 | Visit | 427355 | 0.5 | 11/12/2023 |
| J005 | Purpose | 05 | B | 0501 | Visit | 427355 | 0.5 | 11/12/2023 |

I have duplicate values of the Answer and Customer_ID, so I want to group by Answer , Customer_ID and Max of Last (Activity_Date) and then calculate the total of TotalAnswer.

After Grouping:

| Answer | Customer_ID | TotalAnswer | Activity_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 426766 | 0.5 | 09/12/2023 |
| A | 427355 | 0.5 | 11/12/2023 |
| B | 188237 | 1 | 10/12/2023 |
| B | 402564 | 1 | 08/12/2023 |
| B | 426955 | 1 | 05/12/2023 |
| B | 427355 | 0.5 | 11/12/2023 |
| B | 427441 | 1 | 05/12/2023 |
| B | 427473 | 1 | 07/12/2023 |
| C | 381630 | 1 | 11/12/2023 |
| C | 426766 | 0.5 | 09/12/2023 |

The final Value.
Total Measure =

| Answer | Total Measure |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 5.5 |
| C | 1.5 |
| Total | 8 |

I want to create dax measure about visualize matrix : row is Answer and Value is Total Measure.

I tried the following DAX expression for the Total Measure:

```
Total Measure = 
VAR StartDate = MIN(DimDate[Date]) /* Mark Relationship of DimDate */
VAR EndDate = MAX(DimDate[Date]) /* Mark Relationship of DimDate */
VAR NumDays = MAX(0, EndDate - StartDate + 1)
VAR PreviousStartDate = StartDate - NumDays
VAR PreviousEndDate = EndDate - NumDays
Var PJ = VALUES(DimProject[PJ_CODE])
Return CALCULATE(SUM(TEMP_WQ[TotalAnswer]),GROUPBY(TEMP_WQ,TEMP_WQ[Questionnaire_Type],TEMP_WQ[Questionnaire],TEMP_WQ[Answer]),
            FILTER(
                ALL(TEMP_WQ),
                TEMP_WQ[Activity_Date] >= PreviousStartDate && 
                TEMP_WQ[Activity_Date] <= PreviousEndDate &&
                TEMP_WQ[PJ_CODE] IN PJ &&
                TEMP_WQ[Questionnaire_Type] = "Visit" 
                 )
)
```

But this didnt work either. For every help thanks in advance.

| Answer | Previous1 |
| --- | --- |
| B | 5.5 |
| Total | 5.5 |

I've attach sample SQL query to display my Expected Result. I try to create dax like a SQL query but didn't work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide your expected result ?

Comment: Hi Amira,
I've already update my expect result. Thanks.

Comment: How do you calculate the Previous1 (Sum TotalAnswer)?

Comment: That's Previous1 from my dax code. I've already updated my column from expected result.

Comment: Can you clarify the way you are calculating it ?

Comment: Updated detail in my question. I’ll do my best to explain. If you have any doubts, please feel free to ask me. I’m here to provide you with a thoughtful response.